# Threading in python, error when creating threads with specific string input

Tags: python, multithreading

according to me, weirdest problem that took me forever to figure out because I simply can't fathom what is wrong, anyway here goes:

```
class pod_spawner():

    def __init__(self):
        self.pod_name="Test"

    def bot_creater(self,bot_nr):
        for i in range(5):
            print(bot_nr + " doing its work")
            time.sleep(2)    

    def add_thread(self):
        threading.Thread(name="Something", target=self.bot_creater, args=("1")).start()
```

This is perfectly okay, a `thread` spawns and we are golden however if I change the args input to `args=("bot_1")` instead of just `args=("1")`, "it throws me a `bot_creater() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given"` error.

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `args` takes a tuple, so I'm betting it converting your string into a tuple of characters.

Comment: Okay I am not really following, I have always just put in args=("x","y","z"), how should I do it?

Comment: I'd try `args=("bot_1",)` The `,` forces it to interpret it has a tuple of length 1

Comment: Just did and it works, thanks! If you have time I would greatly appreciate if you could tell me why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemporalWolf is right, it takes a tuple. If you just put brackets round a string, it is just taken to be mathematical brackets. If you add a comma, python interprets it as a tuple:

```
threading.Thread(name="Something", target=self.bot_creater, args=("bot_1",)).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's converting the string input into a tuple, like so:

```
tuple(("bob"))
('b', 'o', 'b')
```

because

```
>>> type(("bob"))
<type 'str'>
```

Instead, you want:

```
>>> tuple(("bob",))
('bob',)
```

because

```
>>> type(("bob",))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Essentially it's ignoring the extra set of parentheses until you give it `(element,)` which then forces it to interpret it as a tuple of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `list` instead if you have one argument, as the following:

```
threading.Thread(name="Something", target=self.bot_creater, args=["bot_1"]).start()
```